# I can't find a way to show lint errors in Android Studios project view

Tags: android, android-studio, lint

In Eclipse, any lint errors or warnings are both highlighted in the code file, but also in the package tree with icons highlighting files with warnings/errors.

Try as I might, I can't find a way to replicate this functionality in Android Studio. Does anyone know of a way to do this? Is there an IntelliJ plugin I just can't find that might help?

Comment: tried the lint check command? (google it if you don't know)

Answer (score 9):

try looking at the error report file located: ProjectDir/app/build/report/lint-results-release-fatal.html

Answer (score 4):

As per android developer docs, we can inspect the lint error below way

1.In the Android view, open your project and select the project, a folder, or a file that you want to analyze.

2.From the menu bar, select Analyze > Inspect Code.

3.In the Specify Inspection Scope dialog, review the settings.

Reference [click here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint)

Answer (score 0):

To manually run inspections in Android Studio, from the application or right-click menu, choose Analyze > Inspect Code.